# How do you characterize the noise in a fluid velocity measurement device?

Tags: noise, measurement, characterization

I have designed and built a measurement device that detects the velocity of a fluid flow (a constant-temperature anemometer). I wanted to experimentally characterize the noise performance of the device according to similar standards used for these devices such as the equivalent input noise. I've included a link to a datasheet to such a commercially available device below.

Datasheet (p.4): https://www.dantecdynamics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/0566_v2_SS_StreamLine-Pro.pdf

Many of the resources I have found on measuring and characterizing the noise of electronic devices use noise sources at the input. However, it would not be possible for this measurement device as the input is the velocity of a fluid, which I can not control to a reasonable degree of accuracy. So, I was wondering: are there are any methods or resources I should look into to experimentally characterize the noise of the anemometer?

Comment: I would think you bypass the phenomena the instrument is *intended* to measure and directly manipulate the mechanism the sensor is actually utilizing. For example, if hot-wire then you directly cool it. If a mechanical anemometer than you directly spin it rather than blowing air through it.

Comment: What is the source of the noise in your sensor?  In electronic devices, the (self-induced) noise is usually caused by the random fluctuation of electrons in the material being used.

Comment: everettA, There's the textbook electronics package answers. But if you are thinking about the transducer itself then It's a process. You start with what you know (theory) and see what the residuals look like. The residuals may suggest a refinement to the theory you had before. You apply the refinement, see if that improves prediction. If it does, you look at the residuals still remaining after that. Ultimately, if you get to the point where the residuals are a good match for Poisson events integrating into Gaussian shaped distributions without further explanation to be had, that's the noise.

Comment: everettA, I'm guessing there may be turbulent flows around the sensor given a liquid. If so, and if you don't possess theory to predict them, they may look inexplicable but are actually able to be explained. It's just that *you personally* can't explain them, lacking the mental tools for it. That's not really noise in usual meaning and various randomness tests will likely fail in a lot of places. Which tells you to either find an expert on the topic to help, one who can develop theory for turbulence, or else consider it 'sensor uncertainty'. It's shape won't be anything like noise, though.

Comment: everettA, it's a never-ending process. And you will find scientists, time to time, uncovering new theory to explain more of prior data. When that happens, the prior data (and new data) acquires a newly improved 'uncertainty' to it. The sensor (or arrays of sensors) didn't change at all. But our understanding *did*.

Comment: SteveSh, I'm not interested in the noise generated by the sensor itself. What I want to characterize is the noise generated by the electronics that incorporate the sensor. In the case of the constant-temperature anemometer, the sensor is placed in a Wheatstone bridge in a feedback loop with a servo amplifier. So, I would want to characterize the noise generated by the Wheatstone bridge and the servo amplifier.

Comment: periblepsis, That is not at all related to what I was asking. I am aware of the presence of turbulent flows and the expected results as predicted by the theory as that is specifically what I am using this measurement device to analyze. I am looking to characterize the noise of the electronics that incorporate the sensor.

Comment: @everettAdams - So then just replace the sensor's output with a resistor in the Wheatstone bridge and measure the output.  You probably want to open the loop up to do this, or maybe it will be opened up anyway without the sensor in place.

Comment: @SteveSh, Sounds good. After measuring the noise from the output of the device, how should the data be presented? I've seen some use an RMS voltage and others refer to the noise power spectrum. Would there be any preference between the two?

Comment: @ederettAdams - I work in the RF world, where almost everything is characterized or measured or analyzed in terms of dB, so power.  In the case of things like noise, we need to take the bandwdith of the system into account.  I'm not sure what would be appropriate for your application.  But you should be able to go back and forth if you know things like the bandwidth involved, impedances (needed to go from power to volts and back again), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to measure the noise of electronics, you can watch this video [Measuring system noise (Texas Instruments)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2UUIUPmwdU). This process can also be found in book "Operational Amplifier Noise: Techniques and Tips for Analyzing and Reducing Noise, Art Kay".

In fact, as SteveSh says, you need to replace the sensor output by a resistor in the Wheatstone bridge, so that it's perfectly balanced to give a measurement equal to 0V. Your system should be placed in a shielded enclosure so as not to be disturbed by the outside environment. And you can use a spectrum analyser to measure the noise of your device.

It's possible to calcul the noise in your device because will consist of thermal noise in the resistors, the broadband voltage and current noise of op amp (or transistor), the 1/f noise of op amp (or transistor), ... All noise sources add up quadratically if they are uncorrelated but is hard.

Answer (score 1):

Usually sensor noise is calculated at the output, but there are a few ways to do specify noise. One is only specify the electronic noise. This can be measured or calculated or both.

If you have an analog signal chain you can calculate the electronic noise in each component and then add the noise into a total noise figure. This can be specified at the input or the output, the difference is usually in the gain between the input and the output.

The input on most sensors can be shorted to measure the intrinsic electronic noise. With the input shorted, the noise can be measured, you can't make a measurement better than that.

The other problem is if you are doing a differential measurement, this will increase the noise if you are doing any kind of subtraction as the noise will be additive. (you don't get less noise when you subtract two noise sources, you get more noise)